# Strange looking pattern matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I came across this code:

```
val f = Future { throw new InterruptedException }
f.failed foreach { case t => log(s"error - $t") }
```

Code makes use of pattern matching.

In pattern matching, a value is compared with a pattern. But I don't see any pattern here. t looks more like the value. So how does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The section [8.1.1 of the spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html) states unambiguously:

> A variable pattern x is a simple identifier which starts with a lower case letter. It matches any value, and binds the variable name to that value.

The variable `t` does start with a lower case letter.

Variable patterns are "simple patterns", which in turn are a special case of the general pattern.

Answer (score 0):

May this can help you

```
/** Asynchronously processes the value in the future once the value becomes available.
   *
   *  WARNING: Will not be called if this future is never completed or if it is completed with a failure.
   *
   *  $swallowsExceptions
   *
   * @tparam U     only used to accept any return type of the given callback function
   * @param f      the function which will be executed if this `Future` completes with a result,
   *               the return value of `f` will be discarded.
   * @group Callbacks
   */
  def foreach[U](f: T => U)(implicit executor: ExecutionContext): Unit = onComplete { _ foreach f }
```

this foreach documentation on Future trait, the internal foreach is called from scala.util.Try.foreach
and there is him declarion.

```
 /**
   * Applies the given function `f` if this is a `Success`, otherwise returns `Unit` if this is a `Failure`.
   *
   * ''Note:'' If `f` throws, then this method may throw an exception.
   */
  def foreach[U](f: T => U): Unit
```

this is the most important thing.
   *  WARNING: Will not be called if this future is never completed or if it is completed with a failure.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't understand your question before response.... but no, if you return a new exception it doesn't gonna throw a exception, it will happen only if you throw that, for example as you made.